# Storm Kafka Spout not commit offset in local cluster , spout retrieves same message repeatedly

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I have set storm topology which gets input data from kafka server. I used kafka-storm package to get data. I have implemented the connection between kafka server and storm topology succesfully in local cluster, but i am facing some issues in retrieving data from kafka server.

kafka Spout retrieves same message repeatedly at runtime even i set `spoutconfig.forceFromStart=false` and `spoutconfig.startOffsetTime =-1`

Note : When i stop and restart the cluster the data is sent correctly based on the lastest offset.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out by myself, the issue is with `outputcollector` `ack()` method. I have implemented the bolt collector with `BaseBasicBolt`, it didn't acknowledge the kafkaspout. I have replace with `BaseRichBolt` and made `this.collector.ack(tuple)` manually.

Now its work fine